# Why is core-select being called twice?

Tags: polymer

I'm working through my [first Polymer example](http://www.polymer-project.org/docs/start/tutorial/step-1.html) and I've reworked the code to be as follows:

```
dom = {}
dom.paperTabs = $('paper-tabs')

;(function() {
    $('paper-tabs').on('core-select',coreSelect)
    function coreSelect(myEvent) {
        console.log(dom.paperTabs.prop('selected'))
    }
})()
```

Q: Why is `core-select` being called twice?
It looks to be doing so in the original as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`core-select` is fired for both selection and deselection. The `event.detail.isSelected` property tells you which is which.

It's done this way so you can add/remove selection filigree (CSS classes for example) without manual bookkeeping.

The documentation is not clear enough on this point, it trips up a lot of people. We are working on it (either improve the docs or change the API).

Comment: Oh, so in my example, I would do my work when myEvent.originalEvent.detail.isSelected is true.